# GSM shield for Arduino Due

Tags: shields, gsm, arduino-due

Is there any good quality GSM shield compatible with Arduino Due?
I have searched for gsm shield but it seems all shields have operation voltage 5v.
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Most GSM modules have native I/O at 3.3v or even lower (2.8v is common), so you would be looking for one that either didn't have level shifters, or had level shifters to a configurable voltage.